# Creating a Microsoft Account on a Windows Phone mobile

Tags: settings, email

I've seen that when setting up a Windows Phone mobile for the first time, we can create a new Microsoft Account. During the process, we also need to enter an "alternative" email address.

I was wondering if we could skip that? Or if it is mandatory to put one to create the new account?

Thank you. (I want to be polite, please don't delete it, I mean it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes
So it seems you're required to enter an alternate phone number if you do not enter an alternate email address.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [microsofts information page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/account-security-password-information) :

> Security info is an alternate email address or phone number you add to your account. If you forget your password, or if someone else is trying to take over your account, we send a security code to that alternate email or phone number. When you send the code back to us, then we know that you’re really you, and we can get you back in to your Microsoft account.

So it seems to be required to enter an alternate phonenumber if you do not enter an alternate email-address. I guess due to their security policies you cannot skip it.

Comment: Thank you,
Yes you're right but I'd like to know what happens if we let this blank.
When we create a Microsoft Account from a PC, we're asked to enter an alternative email address and a phone number and we can choose actually, the two of them or just one of them.

But on a phone, they ask only an alternative email address. What if (let's suppose) we don't have any, because this is going to be the first one ever?) Wouldn't it be clever to ask a phone number instead ? 
Well, thank you anyway !